# Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can anyone please help me in understanding what am i doing wrong here. Downloaded a theme for a client and the whole theme is breaking due to: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined.

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NDvh.png):

Comment: Have you checked to see what the value is of the alleged href?

Comment: Yeah i have the value seems to match up @Pango. have a look yourself. http://www.cogbodyfit.andregibbs.co.uk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
String(that.attr('href')).charAt(0) == '#'
```

I suppose that this is happening because your value is not a string and charAt is a method that returns the character at the specified index in a string.

Comment: Ref to  [jQuery official API](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName), here maybe the reasons: `As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.`